# How to defer execution of Jasmine SpecRunner

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm new to Jasmine. I have a need to launch SpecRunner.html but trigger execution only after some time manually for example from chrome console.

As far as I can see there is a boot method that is automatically executed. How can I prevent it from doing so but run it later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your own boot.js

Modify these lines

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (currentWindowOnload) {
        currentWindowOnload();
    }
    htmlReporter.initialize();
    env.execute();
};
```

to add the additional delay

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (currentWindowOnload) {
        currentWindowOnload();
    }
    htmlReporter.initialize();
    setTimeout(env.execute(), 5000);
};
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Problem is I get htmlReporter undefined

Comment: Then you probably aren't setup correctly in the first place  htmlReporter is defined in the boot.js

Comment: finally I manage to do it by making htmlReporter global so I marked your answer as good answer.

Comment: I habe yet another question on jasmine here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963143/why-i-cant-access-global-variable-from-javascript-function-in-jasmine