# Why I can't access global variable from javascript function in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine standalone https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases

I have declared a global variable global_song in `SpecRunner.html` (I can access it from chrome console so it's truly global) which includes script where I am trying to concatenate global_song to "should be able to play Song " :

```
it("should be able to play Song " + global_song, function() {
player.play(song);
expect(player.currentlyPlayingSong).toEqual(global_song);

//demonstrates use of custom matcher
expect(player).toBePlaying(song);
});
```

Why it cannot access `global_song` variable ?

**Update** : `expect(player.currentlyPlayingSong).toEqual(global_song)` works whereas `it("should be able to play Song " + global_song` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't use Jasmine, but just wondering if the global_song variable is declared by the time that statement executes.

Comment: Is your variable `global_song` being declared before the Jasmine program is being run? Otherwise it won't be defined.

Comment: see my update : expect(player.currentlyPlayingSong).toEqual(global_song) works whereas it("should be able to play Song " + global_song doesn't work

Comment: @user310291 do you use karma as test runner ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko no I don't know karma yet

Comment: @user310291 ohh, i've missed that you mentioned  `SpecRunner.html`. However i've updated my answer with some ideas why you cannot access `global_song` in call of `it`

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined global_song? If you did that in the beforeEach() function this behaviour would make sense as the code in the describe block (which attempts to define your it() function) gets executed before the beforeEach() as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546182/jasmine-why-cant-nested-describe-blocks-see-vars-defined-in-outer-describe) other SO answer.

Comment: as I said I defined global_song in SpecRunner.html, proof I can access this var from chrome console

Comment: expect(player.currentlyPlayingSong).toEqual(global_song) works whereas it("should be able to play Song " + global_song doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well i suppose your `global_song` created after executing of

```
player.play(song);
```

That's way it's not available in test as first parameter of `it` and available after executing `player.play` in `expect(player.currentlyPlayingSong).toEqual(global_song)` assertion.

Try to add simple assignment to `global_song` separatelly from `player.play` to verify that it's available before `player.play` executed:

```
window.global_song = 'value'
```

Just take a look on that sample to illustrate the main possible candidate of problem:

```
function foo(){
    window['bar'] = 'bar';
}

console.log(window.bar); // Undefined
foo(); // now window contain bar variable.
console.log(window.bar); // 'bar'
```